# Rails 3. Live searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a "live search" in Rails 3 using the below guide. I am just a bit afraid that this "query by type" will be very heavy on the database server (I am using Heroku). 
Is searching like this a big no-no or do you guys think it will be ok, even if I got 500 users? Any input is good! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a full-text search engine like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). Look at [this Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need a plugin. I just need to know if performance wise is there a problem with searching this way? Perhaps it is much better for the database if I just count the matching hits than to get them?

Comment: I would not recommend to use this approach in production code. Even if you just count the number of matching hits you fire (at least) one query every time a user hits a key. Imagine only 10 users typing the word "stackoverflow" at the same time, that are 10*13=130 queries in a few seconds, only for live-searching, not including other users browsing your page.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the same tutorial @Aymeric has commented after your query (http://aymeric.gaurat.net/index.php/2010/how-to-develop-live-search-textbox-in-ruby-on-rails/)

and one more thing you can do is to set a limit to the query so that you wont get the whole list

cheers

sameera